# Can't boot after power loss

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I am duel-booting Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 8. I was booted into Ubuntu when I lost power and now when I try to boot into Ubuntu it freezes on a black screen. However I can still boot into Windows just fine. When I boot into recovery mode I get the fallowing error:

```
There are differences between boot sector and its backup.
Differences: (offset: original/backup)
    65:01/00
    Not automatically fixing this
/dev/sda6 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Checking disk drives for errors. This may take several minutes.
Press C to cancel all check in progress
/dev/sda1: 179 files, 7007/126976 clusters
/dev/sda6 Unattached inode 599991
/dev/sda6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
        (i.e., without -a or -p options)
mountall: fsck / [1183] terminated with statas 4
mountall: Filesystem has errors: /

Errors were found while checking the disk drive for /.
Press F to attempt to fix the errors, I to ignore, S to skip mounting, or M for manual recovery
```

I tried pressing 'F' to attempt to fix the errors but nothing happened. Actually I tried pressing all of the mentioned keys ('F', 'I', 'S', and 'M') all on different reboots but the computer was unresponsive.

I am new to Ubuntu and Linux in general so I don't exactly know where to start. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I booted into recovery mode, from there dropped to a root shell and ran the fallowing command:

```
fsck /dev/sda6 -v
```

That seamed to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get an OS choosing screen when PC is booted. So, we have so many options there like Ubuntu, Ubuntu recovery mode(something like that), memtest, Windows 7 etc. Choose recovery mode. May help sometimes. Good luck. Comment!

Comment: Still doesn't boot. But at least gives an error message instead of a black screen. I edited my question to include the error message.

Comment: Press F to attempt to fix the errors...Try that!

Comment: Tried that. Actually I tried pressing all the mentioned keys(F, I, S and M all at different reboots) but the computer gave no response. I should mention that it is not a keyboard error because one time the computer went to sleep at that screen and I pressed a key to wake it up.